# Sklearn: Is MinMaxScaler the right tool?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, facebook-prophet

I use [Prophet](https://github.com/facebook/prophet) to predict ticket sales for live events (concerts). Until now I was working with only one event. To improve predictions I want to chain data from several concerts that are all relevant to the one I am planning to predict for.

Now the challenge is, that each event has a different max. capacity. Therefore selling 10000000 in total_gross for **event_id 1** is as good as selling 5000000 for **event_id 2** (both would be sold out in that case). Some sample data:

```
id  created                         total_gross event_id    max_capacity
1   2019-03-01 10:57:32.381378+00   18760       1   10000000
2   2019-03-01 10:58:30.93307+00    9380        1   10000000
3   2019-03-01 10:58:45.425421+00   7380        1   10000000
4   2019-03-01 10:59:11.588687+00   14760       1   10000000
5   2018-03-01 11:14:15.630797+00   7380        2   5000000
6   2018-03-01 11:14:25.308153+00   36900       2   5000000
7   2018-03-01 11:14:34.781773+00   7380        2   5000000
```

On my [drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7getd.jpg) here you can see on top "before" scaling and in red on the bottom after scaling. I wonder now what's the right way to "transform" my data. Is `MinMaxScaler` the right tool? And would I simply pass these arrays to it as here?

```
np.array([[ total_gross, max_capacity_event_1],
         [ total_gross2,  max_capacity_event_1],
         [ total_gross, max_capacity_event_2],
         [...]])
```

Comment: As `max_capacity` is different for events, you may try predicting percentage of tickets sold instead. Leave `max_capacity` as one of the independent variables and let your algo decide if it's important.

Comment: If I am going for the "not" percentage approach, would MinMaxScaler an appropriate alternative? Or how would you deal with these different values?

Comment: I believe predicting percentage of tickets sold and leaving max_capacity as it is should be better. But the only conclusive answer to your question you can get is by doing cross validation.

Comment: I will go with percentage. It seems to make more sense!